# No hay valor de retorno

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, algoritmos

Hice un programa que me diga si un vector tiene un espacio vacío ( nulo ), pero a la hora de correrlo no me retorna nada. adjunto imagen y código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static boolean arregloLleno(Estudiante estudiantes[]){
    boolean lleno = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < estudiantes.length; i++) {
        if(estudiantes[i] == null){
            lleno = false;
        } else {
            lleno = true;
        } // If
    } // For
    return lleno;
} // arregloLleno
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como todo debug, empezaremos por una sencilla traza con un caso específico, vamos a suponer que tenemos el siguiente array de estudiantes:

```
/* Por cierto, en Java los array se suelen poner en el tipo (Estudiante[] arrayEstudiantes),
 a diferencia de C++ donde suele declararse en la variable en si (Estudiante arrayEstudiantes[]).
 No afecta en nada y ambas son "válidas", pero las normas son las normas*/
Estudiante[] arrayEstudiantes = {new Estudiante("pepito"), null, new Estudiante("jaimito")};
```

Según tu pregunta, este array debería devolver falso, verdad? Pero tu bucle no analiza hasta el primer `null`, si no que sigue! Con lo cual tu flag `lleno` pasará por los siguientes valores (en este caso concreto):

- `arrayEstudiantes[0] == null` -> `false`, aquí el flag `lleno` devolvería, true, correcto!
- `arrayEstudiantes[1] == null` -> `true`, aquí el flag `lleno` devolvería, false, lo que es correcto puesto que tenemos un null!
- `arrayEstudiantes[2] == null` -> `false`, vaya... ahora tenemos otro true, porque el último caso que analizamos, es un estudiante y no un null!

Por qué sucede esto? Porque no utilizas un return una vez que ya sabes que el array tiene al menos *un* `null`

---

Sabiendo esto, y dado que solo necesitas determinar si ***UNO*** de los estudiantes está a `null` para considerar que no está lleno, el código quedaría algo así:

```
public static boolean arregloLleno(Estudiante estudiantes[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < estudiantes.length; i++) {
        if(estudiantes[i] == null){ // Si equivale a null
            return false; // Simplemente devuelve false, no hace falta else ni nada
        } // if
    } // For
    return true; /* Solo llegará a ejecutar esta línea si nunca ha entrado al if, es decir,
    si ninguno de los estudiantes está a null! Así que aquí devuelve true*/
} // arregloLleno
```

---

En cuanto al problema de que no está "devolviendo" nada, si no lo llamas desde dentro de un `System.out.println(arregloLleno(arrayEstudiantes));` nunca vas a ver el resultado en consola, puesto que en la función estás haciendo un `return`, no imprimiendo nada :)